# Loop through dataframe filling new column with 1 and 0 based on other criteria

Tags: python, pandas

```
transaction    startdate
```

1 0 1 0

Comment: Your question and/or your data is a bit confusing to me.  You have a column TransDate then you have columns with dates.  Can you explain again what you want?

Comment: TransDate is the date the transaction takes place and the columns with the dates has to do with schedule information for the cashier in that transaction

Answer (score 1):

Check with `get_indexer` and `values` slice

```
s=df.filter(like='/')
idcol=s.columns.get_indexer(df.TransDate)
df['PreviousDayDummy']=(s.values[np.arange(len(s)),idcol-1]==df.lookup(df.index,df.TransDate)).astype(int) 

df
Out[72]: 
   Transaction TransDate  Cashier  PreviousDayDummy  01/01  01/02  01/03
0            1     01/02        2                 1      1      1      1
1            2     01/02        1                 0      0      1      1
2            3     01/02        2                 1      1      1      1
3            4     01/03        3                 0      0      0      1
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting a KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found'

Comment: Could this have something to do with my entire dataframe having transactions that occur on 01/01 and therefore there is no previous day?

Comment: Is there a way to start at the row that starts at 1/02 or ignore TransDates that are 01/01 as I do not need PreviousDayDummys for those records but I dont think I want to delete them from the dataframe altogether